# How to pass the variable names as they are in array

Tags: php

```php
<?php
function empty_values()
{
    $values = func_get_args();
    while (list(, $value) = each($values))
    {
        if (empty($value))
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
?>
```

I want to pass the values from $_POST like this

```
if (empty_values(implode("," , $_POST)
{
    //some code
}
```

Comment: Hi its not really clear what your question is and you have not accepted @Qirel answer yet so if that is not the answer you are looking for, please add something to your question so that we can understand better what you are asking

Answer (score 0):

Use `array_filter()` instead and compare the length to the length of the `$_POST` array.

```php
if (count($_POST) > count(array_filter($_POST))) {
    // At least one value was empty
}
```